# Generating ripmaps for anisotropic filtering

Tags: opengl

For trilinear filtering, I use gluBuild2DMipmaps to generate mipmaps. Is there anything similar for anisotropic filtering or do I need to generate the ripmaps myself? If the latter is the case, what tools do people use?

Somewhat related: what is the best way to tell my program is actually using anisotropic filtering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anisotropic filtering, as [implemented by OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_filter_anisotropic.txt) and graphics hardware, doesn't use ripmaps. It works by sampling the texture a lot. Mipmaps help *a lot* and will be used when present (and when an appropriate minification filter is used).

Your program doesn't use anisotropic filtering. Individual textures can be anisotropically filtered, just as individual texture may or may not use mipmap filtering and such. Therefore, your question about telling if you program is using it doesn't make sense.

Individual textures will use it if you turn it on for that texture by specifying a non-1.0 max anisotropy value. Drivers can force it on in certain conditions using control panel settings, but there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, essentially I know everything I need to know now. Of course, I was asking for a way to tell whether my program uses anisotropic filtering on a certain texture. I was thinking of a certain pattern on which (the lack of) anisotropic is easy to spot but I suppose a texture with lines along the direction of the camera should do.